# React Router: Refused to execute script or styles

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, reactjs, react-router

When I browse http://localhost:8080/create , its working fine but when browse http://localhost:8080/create/344 or http://localhost:8080/edit/224 I'm getting this error:

> Refused to apply style from
>   'http://localhost:8080/edit/dist/main.css' because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME
>   checking is enabled.
>
> 2345:12 GET http://localhost:8080/edit/dist/bundle.js 404 (Not Found)
>   345:1
>
> Refused to execute script from
>   'http://localhost:8080/editt/dist/bundle.js' because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is
>   enabled.

Here is my code:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditPost}/>
        <Route path="/create" component={AddPost} />
        <Route component={NotFoundPage}/>
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**check this screenshot please:**

[image]

here is my webpack config file: https://pastebin.com/d5vx8niQ
project file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IYcuJTbklXYi53XvIcNRJtb-tLOO4g1j/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm trying for two days, but I couldn't find any solution :(  here is my file you can check https://send.firefox.com/download/91cc3b75a1/#lPUaHFNmniQYtl6zyc-s7g

Comment: when i run a webpack dev server and navigate to a page that doesn't exist, i get a 404 in the browser console, and a number of css and js files trigger the same MIME type error. they trigger that error because if you go to the link for those assets directly you'll see a 404 page generated by webpack *which is HTML* and not CSS or JS like your app is expecting. it's a typo error, but it's not quite obvious from what webpack is throwing you

Answer (score 11):

Add `<base href="/">` in index.html head before linking all css files.
(Source: https://github.com/froala/angular-froala/issues/170)

Answer (score 2):

**Just use** `/dist/main.css` & `/dist/bundle.js` instead of `dist/main.css` & `dist/bundle.js` in your HTML.